# Omitting the article before an enumeration of technical tasks

Tags: definite-articles, uncountable-nouns

I have the following sentence:

> Acquisition, processing, analysis, and visualization of big data pose
>   challenges at all layers of a computer system.

Should I omit a "The" at the beginning of the sentence or is the "The" required, since the words are not common mass nouns?

Comment: 'The' is optional here, but I'd say it's more common to include it in running prose (as here), though not in titles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To not leave this question unanswered, I copy Edwin's comment here:

> 'The' is optional here, but I'd say it's more common to include it in running prose (as here), though not in titles.